# SqlCommand UPDATE not update the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters, sql-update

Edit1: "You can't parameterize identifiers in sql. SET @Column = @Value will not work."

So if I modify the datagridview, I can't make an iteration where I tell the sql server which columns should be updated? Do I need to update every element of the row? Thanks for the other advices too.

I'm trying to update my SQL Server database with this C# code:

```
try 
{
    string parancs = "UPDATE Equipment SET @Column = @Value, Modifier = @Modifier, Modified = @Modified " +
                     "WHERE Description = @Description AND [Plane_A/C] = @Plane";

    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(parancs, connection);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows) 
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) 
        {
            if (cell.Value == null) 
            {
                cell.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    sqlComm.Connection.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowIndexes.Count; i++) 
    {
        sqlComm.Parameters.Clear();
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column", dataGridView.Columns[columnIndexes[i]].HeaderText);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", dataGridView.Rows[rowIndexes[i]].Cells[columnIndexes[i]].Value);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", dataGridView.Rows[rowIndexes[i]].Cells["Description"].Value);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plane", ChoosenAC);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modifier", "TesztAdmin");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified", time);

        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    sqlComm.Connection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Sikeres módosítás!");
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

`rowIndexes.Count` is the number of the modified rows and columnIndexes are their positions. The code run without exception, but the data wont update. In SQL Server Profiler I get this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Equipment SET @Column = @Value, Modifier = @Modifier, Modified = @Modified WHERE Description = @Description AND [Plane_A/C] = @Plane',N'@Column nvarchar(11),@Value float,@Description nvarchar(6),@Plane nvarchar(8),@Modifier nvarchar(10),@Modified datetime',@Column=N'InspectHour',@Value=800,@Description=N'Engine',@Plane=N'TEST-REP',@Modifier=N'TesztAdmin',@Modified='2017-09-27 12:44:14.773'
```

So all of the parameters get values. If I copy the `UPDATE` command to SSMS and use exact values instead of parameters, it works fine and update.

When I use the same method in the program with INSERT command instead of UPDATE, it works without problem. I hope I wrote down everything and you could help.

Tibor

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in sql. `SET @Column = @Value` will not work.

Comment: What is the use of `@Column`? You can not pass the column to be updated as a parameter in command for sure. Try removing that parameter and putting specific column name in the command. Then see it works fine.

Comment: I think they have a table column called "Column". the table is a property bag. This is not about parametrization of a column identifier. As to why the assignment of @Column is shown with @ in the profiler output, is a different story. note how the following assignments are not.

Comment: Why you don't update all columns at once?

Comment: he is iterating over *rows*. @Tibor, please show your table schema and why is there an @ prefix on the first column name in your update statement text?

Comment: You don't need to create new parameters in every loop iteration. You can create them outside the loop and change the values inside the loop. This will be more efficient and also prevent you from using `AddWithValue` which is bad practice.

Comment: "The code run without exception" @Tibor If so, why it is enclosed in a `try/catch` block? Having all of your code in a `try/catch` block is a bad practice. It prevents you to find out what exactly is going wrong when it doesn't work. Trap only the errors that are outside of your control - e.g. database calls. All your other code lines should be factored out from the `try/catch` block. Prevent all the errors you can predict in advance - e.g. `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Word `chosen` is with one `o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment I made, I can offer an improved code sample:

```
const string parancs = 
    "UPDATE Equipment SET {column-name} = @Value, Modifier = @Modifier, Modified = @Modified " +
    "WHERE Description = @Description AND [Plane_A/C] = @Plane";

DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            cell.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}

using (connection)
using (var sqlComm = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowIndexes.Count; i++)
    {
        sqlComm.Parameters.Clear();
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", dataGridView.Rows[rowIndexes[i]].Cells[columnIndexes[i]].Value);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", dataGridView.Rows[rowIndexes[i]].Cells["Description"].Value);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plane", ChoosenAC);
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modifier", "TesztAdmin");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modified", time);

        sqlComm.CommandText = parancs.Replace("{column-name}", dataGridView.Columns[columnIndexes[i]].HeaderText);

        try
        {
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    sqlComm.Connection.Close();
}

MessageBox.Show("Sikeres módosítás!");
```

Note, that the `try/catch` block now contains a single line - the database call. It could produce error(s) that is out of our control.

Further, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` implement [Disposable Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) so they need to be used in a `using` block, in order to prevent [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).